# Ubuntu 17.10 [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE

Tags: drivers, intel, microcode

I've installed the newest Ubuntu 17.10 and I am getting this error during boot:
Code:

```
[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x25 (or later)
```

The systems boots up without any other problem, everything seems to be working OK. The system is fully updated.
I am wondering why is this error showing. My notebook model is Lenovo ThinkPad 450s and has the latest drivers installed.

My CPU model is:
Code:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5300U CPU @ 2.30GHz (family: 0x6, model: 0x3d, stepping: 0x4)
```

I am running this system under the latest VMware Player 14.0.0 build-6661328 (Windows 7 64-Bit).
Under this VM, Intel VT-x/EPT is enabled.

Comment: No solutions that I can offer but here is the Launchpad bug report for this problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1724650

Comment: thank you, this helped me I somehow didn't find that page.

Comment: See [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984970/firmware-bug-tsc-deadline-disabled-due-to-errata-what-should-i-do-about-thi)