# [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata - what should I do about this?

Tags: log, bug-reporting, firmware

I saw several bugs and error messages when I was looking by chance into the tool called "logs".

Being a newbie in Ubuntu I have no idea how to deal with these bugs, where to report them or how to fix them.  Any help to guide me here?

The bug I have (which is listed under important) reads:

```
[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x52 (or later)
```

Comment: might be [related](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966642/ubuntu-17-10-firmware-bug-tsc-deadline)

Comment: Search AskUbuntu for the key text related to each bug. All have probably been asked and answered already. Example: The 'DEADLINE' notification is not a bug at all - it's notifying you to take an action.

Comment: Assuming this is just an *example* and you really *are* looking for information on how to report bugs, rather than for how to solve that particular problem, see [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) As for this *specific* problem, I believe [N0rbert's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/984971/22949) should help you.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just install intel-microcode with `sudo apt-get install intel-microcode` and reboot.

If it does not help, try to update your BIOS.

It was already reported to launchpad as [bug 1724650](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-microcode/+bug/1724650).

Comment: I tried your first suggestion and now this bug is gone from my log :-)  There are still other things of course, so I'll try to look around and see how they can be fixed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: +1. One small thing, you might need to enable restricted repo first to install/update `intel-microcode`.

Comment: How can I enable restricted PPA please?  Very ignorant about linux I'm afraid ;(

Comment: @NermeenHussein It might already be enabled. If not, you can [open "Software & Updates" and enable it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlsXc.png).

Comment: Ok, I opened it and the item you highlighted is already ticked.

Comment: How can I run sudo if I'm in BusyBox and can't login in Ubuntu?

Comment: thank you so much! :) had problems booting gentoo and i went nutz! emerging intel-miicrocode resolved it.

Comment: How should I sudo if I stuck in intramfs? Event if I try to load from usb stick, I still end up with "Unable to find a medium containing a live file system"

Comment: I run from live CD where this bug message arrive. Should I install microcode in Live CD. And my os installation from live CD is stuck in detecting file system. I don't know this situation is occurred whether for this bug or not. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039487/18-04-installation-stuck-in-detecting-file-system