# Updating intel microcode before installation?

Tags: system-installation, microcode

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu (I've tried 16.04, 17.10 and 18.04 daily build). Each time I encounter an error when the image is booting, something along the lines of TSC_DEADLINE error, update microcode. I've read some people have had success with updating their motherboard bios but this didn't help me, unfortunately. Other solutions appear to be related to those who already have Ubuntu installed.

Is there a way to alter the iso with the new microcode before installation?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try using the 17.10.1 ISO to build a bootable Ubuntu Live DVD and retry. Post the exact error message in your question, if it still occurs.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/984970/firmware-bug-tsc-deadline-disabled-due-to-errata-what-should-i-do-about-thi

Comment: @karel and **Close Voters** The duplicate candidate requires you have Ubuntu installed before you can modify the installer. The problem here is the OP can't install Ubuntu. Additionally it sounds like the "Try without installing" option isn't even working.

Comment: Thanks WinEunuuchs2Unix, that is correct - I can't boot in to 'Try without installing'. 

Heynnema - thanks, but I have already tried a 17.10 live USB but I can't boot it in to the OS."TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode"