# 18.04 installation stuck in detecting file system

Tags: system-installation, 18.04

[image]

[image]

I tried many time to install 18.04 LTS, but all time shows it takes more than one hour to detect the file system. Then I restart the installation.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.8 GiB, 1921843200 bytes, 3753600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2b192737

Device       Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/loop0p1 *          0 3753599 3753600  1.8G  0 Empty
/dev/loop0p2      3672780 3677451    4672  2.3M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)


Disk /dev/loop1: 1.7 GiB, 1831378944 bytes, 3576912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 86.6 MiB, 90759168 bytes, 177264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 140 MiB, 146841600 bytes, 286800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 1.6 MiB, 1691648 bytes, 3304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 12.2 MiB, 12804096 bytes, 25008 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 21 MiB, 22003712 bytes, 42976 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 3.3 MiB, 3411968 bytes, 6664 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3175fab9

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 136718335 136716288  65.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       777562112 968583167 191021056  91.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       136718336 273436671 136718336  65.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       273438718 777560573 504121856 240.4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       273438720 289062911  15624192   7.5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       289064960 582242303 293177344 139.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       582242367 777560573 195318207  93.1G 83 Linux

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 7 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.




Disk /dev/sdb: 14.5 GiB, 15524167680 bytes, 30320640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0157e4dd

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 30320639 30318592 14.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

When I start the live CD there is a error message

```
[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x22 (or later)
```

The recommended version no(`0x22`) may be different, I can't remember.

Is my installation stuck for this bug?

And there is a solution for this bug message in [[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata - what should I do about this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984970/firmware-bug-tsc-deadline-disabled-due-to-errata-what-should-i-do-about-thi) where they propose to use `sudo apt-get install intel-microcode`. Should I install this in liev CD?

Comment: Please use existing tags instead of repeatedly creating your own. That you have the privilege to create tags doesn't mean you should create them whenever you want.

Comment: I do have the same issue.
Can you boot into the live USB and show a screenshot of gparted? I want to see if the problem I think occurs is the same with yours. 
I found out that my windows partition was mounted on /cdrom - and when it unmounted this partition - it failed.

Comment: @denNorske Making the bootable USB using Unetbootin I have installed successfully. Now, I have not the damaged bootable USB. I previously made bootable using multisystem. Try, unetbootin.

Comment: @alhelal thanks for your heads up. Tried both unetbootin and universal USB installer. Both situations make me get stuck on unmounting /cdrom after clicking "install now".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\[Firmware Bug\]: TSC\_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata - what should I do about this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984970/firmware-bug-tsc-deadline-disabled-due-to-errata-what-should-i-do-about-thi)

Answer (score 1):

This has been a problem for years. It is caused by the `set -e` at the top of `/bin/partman-commit`. When the unmount step fails (because there is a file system that is hosting the loop device on which the installation media is being accessed that is in use) `partman-commit` exits immediately. It never gets to execute anything else in `/lib/partman/commit.d`, and it never signals ubiquity, the installer (its last step). So ubiquity hangs forever.

#### Workaround:

Edit `/bin/partman-commit` and change the `set -e` to `set -x`

Comment: Sorry, the folder commit.d has 10 files. Where do I change the set? Thanks

Comment: This worked for me, but I also unticked "download updates while installing", and unmounted the HD before starting the install process rather than letting the GUI installer unmount it.