# Getting this when I click on Try Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, visual-artifacts

I'm getting this when I click on *Try Ubuntu* or when installing ubuntu. it's uefi bios. my pc have intel pentium g3240. I tried mbr and gpt but still getting this.
Edit: it was happening with every linux distro and today I tried Android x86 with no hardware acceleration and it booted and fine. So please tell me if there's no hardware acceleration in Ubuntu.

[image: error photo]

[image: error photo 2]

Comment: Try to change setting for UEFI from BIOS.

Comment: *I Tried everything* can't quite explain it. tell us what have you tried? be specific and answers will come up. are you using a Nvidia card? what version of ubuntu are you trying? is it Legacy or UEFI? what is the model number of your laptop?

Comment: If you install you can then identify your graphics card and try installing additional drivers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\[Firmware Bug\]: TSC\_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata - what should I do about this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984970/firmware-bug-tsc-deadline-disabled-due-to-errata-what-should-i-do-about-thi)

Answer (score 0):

it seems your system has trouble with video driver
you can try xorg open-source driver by typing this in terminal(may not work with try ubuntu as it does not have persistent storage)

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel`

Comment: how to do it as i can't use the pc when screen flickering happens

Comment: ctrl+alt+f2 will open the terminal.you might want to purge xserver-xorg-video-intel first,if it is present.

Comment: Please check the edited post.