# TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata - when "trying" Ubuntu

Tags: boot, live-usb

I have **Windows 10 Pro** installed on my 120GB SSD and now there is not enough space even to install win 10 update because some application automatically selects C:\ drive to installation localtion. So I decided to download Ubuntu and put it on a USB drive and "try" it so I don't need to install it. And with Ubuntu I can move all program files to a different drive and I can make a symlink to the files.
The problem is that when I try to boot Ubuntu I get a single line saying: **[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x52 (or later)**
I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984970/firmware-bug-tsc-deadline-disabled-due-to-errata-what-should-i-do-about-thi) question, but if I can't boot up Ubuntu I can't use the `sudo apt-get install intel-microcode` command.

So how can I boot this up?

Comment: Consider to download newest dot release of installer - something like Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS or Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS - see http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/ .

Comment: I have **ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64** downloaded.

Comment: I have both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 installed on a 120GB SSD and I have **Users** and **home partition** on a 1TB HDD. This works well, and after more than a year of use I still have lots of space left. This arrangement is easy to set up.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I want to achive the same thing, but because windows uses some files I can't move it and create a symlink. This is why I need Ubuntu.

Comment: In such case try to upgrade the BIOS of your motherboard - as it should contain newer microcode.

Comment: @N0rbert Yes, it works now I can boot Ubuntu. Thanks you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\[Firmware Bug\]: TSC\_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata - what should I do about this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984970/firmware-bug-tsc-deadline-disabled-due-to-errata-what-should-i-do-about-thi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such case try to upgrade the BIOS of your motherboard - as it should contain newer microcode.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Advanced Options and select a previous kernel (keep trying until one works if you find that some don't work). Once inside you'll have the option to bring up a root command prompt which is where you can type in `sudo apt-get install intel-microcode`. In my case I ran out of space during a kernel update which caused it to fail, you can fix it by running `sudo apt-get update`.

Answer (score 0):

Just went through the same issue, almost threw motherboard to trash - but finally checked all connections inside PC and OS drive had disconnected power cable. Plugged in and all works fine.