# Ubuntu 18.04 having kernel panic on boot

Tags: boot, kernel

I tried to boot into Ubuntu 18.04 today, but when it was starting up and all the output was running by it declared a kernel error and froze. The only way I could get out was by holding the power button down for about ten seconds to shut the computer down. I think I might be able to fix the problem if I can get on Ubuntu or even into recovery mode, but I can't do either. I have had Ubuntu for almost nine months and have never had this problem before.
The last time I was on the system it worked normally and I didn't do anything major. The only change I have made to any system that is even related to boot since I was last on was to change the default boot value in the Grub menu. I have a dual boot of Kali Linux (I am using the Kali Grub menu) and Windows 10 (which I am currently on) on the same system, but they have both been working fine.
Before the kernel error the output said something like:

```
[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x22 (or later)
```

The system also kept talking about the VFS but I don't know why because in BIOS the VFS tab is blanked out and it has never had a problem before.

My problem is not a duplicate of this issue because I am stuck outside of my system, not just reading the logs through: [[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata - what should I do about this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984970/firmware-bug-tsc-deadline-disabled-due-to-errata-what-should-i-do-about-thi)

[Image of my screen during kernel panic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5UkO.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\[Firmware Bug\]: TSC\_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata - what should I do about this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984970/firmware-bug-tsc-deadline-disabled-due-to-errata-what-should-i-do-about-thi)

Comment: This is different because I am stuck outside of the system and can't get in. Not just reading through the logs.

Comment: Then update your BIOS to the newest version (get it from the motherboard/laptop manufacturer site).

Comment: I did this and when I got to the part about Flashing the system it said that my BIOS was on a higher system than the one in the update file, so I canceled the upgrade or 'downgrade'. My computer is refurbished. I wonder if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Okay, I believe I caused the issue when I changed the default boot option for GRUB and updated it. I am using the Kali GRUB menu, which complicates things, since my problem is with Ubuntu. I believe the problem is with the initramfs, but I can't figure out how to fix it. I can boot into Ubuntu on one of my older kernels, but still cannot with the current one. Suggestions would be appreciated for fixing the problem.

Comment: ...and why not tell us what boot options you've changed? If it is a secret, can you at least tell if you've tried reverting the changes.

Comment: The problem started when I updated the default boot option in the GRUB menu with Kali. I did it like this: https://www.sajeeva.net/articles/change-default-boot-order-grub-kali-linux-dual-boot-system/