# Can I install Ubuntu 18.04 and bring data over from another Ubuntu 18.04 installation on the same computer

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have had Ubuntu for quite some time now and recently I have been having some problems with the generic drivers that have been causing kernel crashes and so many things went wrong that I can't fix anything because every problem keeps me from fixing the others. I discussed the problem about the generic drivers here: [Ubuntu 18.04 having kernel panic on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107983/ubuntu-18-04-having-kernel-panic-on-boot) and I never found a fix.
Now I have decided that the easiest thing to do will be to boot Ubuntu fresh from a CD onto the computer in a different partition and then delete the old one. Now, I am wondering if there is a way to transfer my personal files from the previous partition (my personal files are fine despite the problems I have been having) into the my new boot as I am installing it. Is it even possible or would it pollute my new installation as well? Is it better to transfer the files manually after the installation? I also have Kali Linux and Windows 10 running on the same machine.

Comment: It is possible "to transfer my personal files". In fact, all important file should be backed up. I don't know what you mean by "pollute my new installation". I also don't know what you mean by "Is it better to transfer the files manually...". Better as opposed to what? Please try to add some clarity to the above.

Comment: When I say "pollute my new installation" I mean that I don't want to bring the files across that may be causing my problem and when I say "Is it better to transfer the files manually..." I mean should I install the new Ubuntu, open the old Ubuntu's files system, and then transfer my personal files by copying them across, which is probably what I will end up doing.

Comment: So, "the generic drivers that have been causing kernel crashes" are, in fact,  "my personal files"? The mist just got thicker.

Comment: "My personal files" are the apps, programs, and documents that I have created that do not come with the system. The only program that I believe has anything to do with my issues that is not default is Virtual Box which has anyways caused me problems with dpkg.

Comment: OK, good luck with the reinstall then. No more crashes I hope.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a backup to the cloud or external media and do a complete new install if you copy your config files from your old install to the new one your more than likely going to bring those problems into the new install. So I recommend against doing that.
Do the Clean install an overwrite the old install completely.
Just MHO.