# My Linux install bricked itself (ACPI, Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e and PKCS#7)

Tags: fstab

I woke up today, pressed power button and got this screen.
[image]
I did some research and uninstalled nvidia drivers, which caused pkcs errors to go away. More research, and enabling secure boot caused uefi thing to go away. So it looks like this now.
[image]
I have no clue what's going on, I just migrated to Linux from Windows a week ago and I am upset it bricked itself.

I can type `startx` and go to desktop as root but internet does not work and I don't really know what to do. (startx would not boot to desktop before I removed nvidia drivers which was version 390 by the way).
I am using kubuntu 18.04.1.

Some help would be nice.

(specs: Asus z170i pro gaming, i5-6400, evga gtx 1060)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

answering my own question here for visibility, the ACPI errors and PKCS in the log actually have nothing to with the real problem i had. gonna quote my own comment from the other answer.

"Alright, so I found the issue. Yesterday I formatted one of my drives to ext4 from ntfs because the specific application required me to use ext4 partition. However, I didn't made necessary changes to /etc/fstab to let the system know it's no longer NTFS. To fix this, I had to remove extra drive mount points from that file, save, reboot."

basically, it just got stuck on this step of the boot process because it was unable to mount the drive.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and answering, I've had similar fstab problems and they can be quite mysterious - no helpful error messages. Good to reinforce the ever useful question "what did I change recently?"

Comment: I agree with @OrganicMarble. I might add most users get `ACPI` messages and they are sometimes mistaken as fatal error messages when they are not the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can glean, the kernel is finding a known bug, since it cites the errata and asks you to modify microcode with a newer version.

I would need to know more from kernel and about your hardware and software configs.

What device is that?  Sound card? Power interface, I had some problems a while ago with my Lenovo.

This might relate:  [Ubuntu 17.10 [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966642/ubuntu-17-10-firmware-bug-tsc-deadline)

Consensus looks to indicate you need to load new microcode:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/microcode

I see, this looks akin to your issue:

[ACPI Errors - Ubuntu 16.04/17.04 can not be installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/954706/acpi-errors-ubuntu-16-04-17-04-can-not-be-installed)

Looks like you can get grub to hang in there longer and allow more ACPI errors and still boot.

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_rev_override=5"

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: You tell me.  Was there a question in it?

Comment: i remember removing `intel-microcode` package because it caused a problem with something else but that was a week ago and it worked fine for a week. maybe an update that depended on it got installed and it bricked it self.

Comment: Sounds right.  Thanks for that https://askubuntu.com/users/464666/kyuunex

Comment: installing `iucode-tool` and `intel-microcode` made that firmware bug message disappear but other messages are still there.

Comment: Some of those can be ignored, does the system boot now?

Comment: nope, it's stuck on this screen unless i press enter and then type startx, that takes me to desktop as root without internet access

Comment: I see, this looks akin to your issue:  

https://askubuntu.com/questions/954706/acpi-errors-ubuntu-16-04-17-04-can-not-be-installed

Looks like you can get grub to hang in there longer and allow more ACPI errors and still boot.

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_rev_override=5"

Comment: Alright, so I found the issue. Yesterday I formatted one of my drives to ext4 from ntfs because the specific application required me to use ext4 partition. However, I didn't made necessary changes to /etc/fstab to let the system know it's no longer NTFS. To fix this, I had to remove extra drive mount points from that file, save, reboot.

Comment: feel free to edit your answer and add this for visibility. and thank you for helping!

Comment: I just changed it now, you are welcome, hope this helped you !